What is stopping me from buying a single blade (without owning a server rack) for a home server?
I've worked with servers for a while, but beyond a small RaspberryPi for home testing I've never ran my own server from home.
I've been made aware of a site that aggregates a bunch of ebay listings for single blades and it almost seems too good to be true. I'm looking at a single blade for £50 and 300gb of space with 16GB of ram. It has all the connectors I could want in the back.
I don't have a server rack at home, would it be a good idea to buy one for general server usage?
Is it incredibly loud?
Would it overheat?
What are the downsides to making this purchase, beyond the obvious risks of running a server out of my house?

If you actually mean blades, then you need a blade chassis, which are enormous, heavy, loud, and power hungry. Blades are missing most connectors, they depend on the chassis.
If by "blade" you actually mean pizza-box server (which I think is going on, when you say it does have all the connectors you want) then sure, you can get that. it will still be kinda big, kinda loud, but it doesn't really need to be in a rack. You just need room for it somewhere.

You'll need a blade chassis to supply power. It will probably be loud; server hardware is optimized for cooling, not noise level.
In addition it's old when it's 50£, and 300GB spinning drives are slow. Unless you need server functionality and scalability, it's probably better to buy a desktop computer for home lab use.
